# SFTP connection issue with DefaultSftpSessionFactory

Tags: spring, sftp, spring-integration, jsch

I am trying to connect to one particular SFTP server with `org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory`.

Connection is lost right after establishing connection.

```
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: failed to send channel request
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Request.write(Request.java:65)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.RequestSftp.request(RequestSftp.java:47)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.start(ChannelSftp.java:217)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:208)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:145)
    at
```

With the same library I connect to several different SFTP servers without any issues.

Then I tried to connect from command line with below command but failed.

> ```
> sftp -oIdentityFile=sftp_user_rsa -oUser=sftp_user sftp.zzzz.com
> ```

After trying quite a few times with different parameters I connected after specifying a subsystem.

> sftp -oIdentityFile=sftp_user_rsa -oUser=sftp_user
>   -s/usr/libexec/sftp-server sftp.zzzz.com

Also filezilla connects without any issues.

Under the hood DefaultSftpSessionFactory is using sftp channel and setting subsystem to be sftp. 
That part is hard coded.

Is there any way to use a different subsystem with this library?

Many thanks

---

After extending the library (Spring integration SFTP) and the library it is using (JSch) still not working. Even when changed the RequestSftp from source as follows and replaced the hard coded subsystem;

```
 public class RequestSftp extends Request{   
     RequestSftp(){
     setReply(true);   
 }   
 public void request(Session session, Channel channel) throws Exception{
     super.request(session, channel);

     Buffer buf=new Buffer();
     Packet packet=new Packet(buf);
     packet.reset();
     buf.putByte((byte)Session.SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST);
     buf.putInt(channel.getRecipient());
     buf.putString(Util.str2byte("subsystem"));
     buf.putByte((byte)(waitForReply() ? 1 : 0));
     buf.putString(Util.str2byte("the-new-subsystem"));
     write(packet);   
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please open an ['Improvement' JIRA Issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT). Currently, you will have to subclass (or clone) the `DefaultSftpSessionFactory` and `DefaultSftpSession`, overriding the `getSession()` method in the factory. Unfortunately, `connect()` in the session is package-private so you can't simply override that.

It looks like you would just have to change these two lines

```
SftpSession sftpSession = new SftpSession(jschSession);
sftpSession.connect();

MySftpSession sftpSession = new MySftpSession(jschSession);
sftpSession.connect(subsystem);
```

Where `subsystem` would be a property on `MySftpSessionFactory` and `connect(String subsystem)` would be similar to `connect()` on SftpSession.

However, I notice that `getSession()` uses some other private methods (such as `initJschSession`) so it might be easier to just copy the factory and give it a new name. I hate to suggest that, but it's not very friendly for subclassing right now. Please make a note of it in the JIRA issue (in addition to adding the subsystem, we should make the factory easier to subclass.